# Using makefile to link cimgui to project?

Tags: c++, c, user-interface, cmake, makefile

I have a c project and I'm trying to link the C binding for imgui to it using Makefiles but I'm having some trouble. I've already generated the .dll using cmake in a build folder, these are the contents of it:

```
C:\path\to\cimgui\build:
-CMakefiles
-cimgui.dll
-cmake_install.txt
-CMakeCache.txt
-libcimgui.dll.a
-Makefile
```

and this is my makefile

```
PROJ                 := proj
TARGET               := $(PROJ)
OBJ                  := sub.o main.o

INCLUDE_PATH         := -IC:\path\to\SDL2 -IC:\path\to\cimgui
LIB_PATH             := -LC:\path\to\SDL2\lib -LC:\path\to\cimgui\build
LINKER_FLAGS         := -lSDL2 -lopengl32 -lcimgui -lcimgui.dll

CFLAGS               := $(INCLUDE_PATH)

.PHONY               : build clean

build : $(TARGET).exe

$(TARGET).exe: $(OBJ)
    gcc $^ $(LIB_PATH) $(LINKER_FLAGS) -o $@

sub.o: sub.c sub.h
    gcc -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

main.o: main.c sub.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean :
    @rm -fv *.o
    @rm -fv *.exe
```

and this is my main.c project

```
#define CIMGUI_DEFINE_ENUMS_AND_STRUCTS
#include "cimgui.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_opengl.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
      return 0;
}
```

This is the error I get when i try to compile my makefile:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcimgui.dll
```

Comment: Shouldn't "-lcimgui.dll" be just "-lcimgui" ?

Comment: @JesperJuhl that is probably meant to include file `libcimgui.dll.a`. Also `-lcimgui` is already present in the linker flags.

Comment: make sure the `C:\path\to\cimgui\build` has no bank spaces, or just add double-quotes.